# Is it possible to use Wireframe on a 3D gltf x-model in HTML?

Tags: html, three.js, model, 3d, gltf

I'm trying to achieve this:
https://threejs.org/examples/?q=wireframe#webgl_materials_wireframe

By following this tutorial:
https://keithclark.co.uk/articles/3d-models-in-html-documents/

I've already implemented model, made a materials and textures for it but as far i've achieved something like this: https://tomb.pl/projects/laptop/

But this wireframes (in my example) are just textures i would like to get a real wireframes as a rendered model materials. Is it possible this way? Or should i change direction? (I would like to stick to the x-model possibilities cause it will be great way to implement models in the future).

I've already found a material code inside glTF file

```
{
        "alphaMode": "OPAQUE",
        "doubleSided": true,
        
        "emissiveFactor": [
            0.0,
            0.0,
            0.0
        ],
        "extensions": {
            "KHR_materials_unlit": {}
        },
        "name": "lines",
        
        "pbrMetallicRoughness": {
            "baseColorTexture": {
                "extensions": {
                    "KHR_texture_transform": {
                        "scale": [
                            -1.0,
                            -1.0
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "index": 0
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my main material but is it possible to change it via this code?
Appreciate every answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... if no one knows i've switched to xeogl - much better and faster results.
Also i believe better performance. Here is the final result:
https://tomb.pl/projects/examples/effects_ghost_materials.html